# How do you pronounce Houyhnhnm?

Tags: gullivers-travels, jonathan-swift

In *Gulliver's Travels* by Jonathan Swift, Gulliver travels to a land of Houyhnhnms. When I read, I like to hear the names in my head because it helps me to get into the story. However, I do not know how to pronounce Houyhnhnm. Do we have any guidance from Swift, the word's origins, or other sources for how to pronounce Houyhnhnm? If so, how do they recommend?

Comment: Not an answer, because I haven't checked anything; but I think (1) it's clearly meant to sound like a neighing or whinnying horse and (2) you should think of it as Houy-hn-hmn; if I were writing the way I say it phonetically it might come out as "whee-h'n-h'm" or something of the kind.

Comment: I have heard it pronounced *who-nee-him*, and this is how I vocalise it.

Comment: However, acceptable pronunciations can be found easily enough [online](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Houyhnhnm).

Comment: The correct answer to this question is No.

Comment: -1 a google search could've found you the answer. In addition, this really has more to do with pronunciation than literature itself.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I've always imagined it was imitative of the, more conversational sounding, whicker.

Comment: I'm not a horse expert, but of the two good English dictionaries I have access to, one (the OED) defines it as "to whinny" and the other (Chambers) defines it as "to neigh", so while you may well be right I'm not in a position to comment further on these subtleties.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Houyhnhnm), either `\ˈhwi-nəm\` or  `\hü-ˈi-nəm\`. (hwi-num or who-i-num)
The upside e is a schwa, representing a light and unaccented "uh" sound.

That's about it.

Answer (score 7):

The word's origin is in mimicking the whinny of a horse, which is after all what the Houyhnhnms are.

To my knowledge Swift never gave more specific pronunciation guides than that. There's probably no precise human equivalent, just as mung-mung, guau-guau, and woof-woof are all ways that humans try to reproduce the sound of a dog.

My English professor rendered it as "whin-in-im", and I'm sure her colleagues had a whole host of variations. I think that any of them is more or less equally valid. English speakers do have some experience in that initial aspiration, at least those in places that haven't undergone the [wine-whine merger](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wine-whine_merger).

The extra h's in "Houyhnhnm" do imply more aspiration in the ns, but I think that's more important in the written than spoken form. Pronouncing it would be a bit like switching accents in the middle of a sentence, for an accent you don't really speak. With a natural language it would risk sounding pretentious.

So, when called on, I mimick my old English prof, just because that's what gets the point across. I'd say that any other set of speakers pronouncing the word will end up in the vicinity of that, and mimic each other to reach a consensus, but that's neither more nor less right than any of their original pronunciations.

Comment: When you say *my old English professor*, do you mean: (1) your elderly professor of English (2) your professor of Anglo-Saxon (2) your former professor of English (4) your elderly professor from England (5) your former professor from England (6) some combination thereof? Inquiring minds want to know. 

Comment: She was young at the time... but that was 30 years ago. I need a whole new tense structure for that.

I also had an Old English professor, who was quite young, though he'll never be as young as he was then.

Comment: I once met an Old English sheepdog. He was a puppy named Beowoof.